# spring gradle bootrun ignores web xml / custom dispatcher servlet configuration NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am trying to set up a Spring MVC application which uses the Spring JDBC template. I have just one problem that Spring does not seem to pick up my configuration of the bean for the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     version="2.4"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
               http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        WEB-INF/desk-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<display-name>Desk</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>desk</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>desk</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

desk-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/desk_db;instance=SQLEXPRESS"/>
    <property name="username" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="pass"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapplication.desk.mvc, com.myapplication.desk.persistence, com.myapplication.desk.service"/>

<context:annotation-config/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

And in my code I implemented a DAO class for handling the database layer for my application which wires the bean likes this:

```
@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

When I test my application with "gradlew - bootRun" I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate]
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire 
candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I have made all other configuration annotation based which seems to be picked up well. So I have two questions:

1. How could I define this bean in my code?
2. How can I make Spring pick up my configuration?

Any tips are very much appreciated! Thank you so much for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Spring Boot doesn't do anything with your web.xml nor with your application configuration. I suggest you first take a look at the Spring Boot [Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/) and what it does for you. Basically, what you have posted, you can remove everything, put your properties for the datasource in an `application.properties` file, create a class with a main method which launches your application. Spring Boot will configure everything for you.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem

1. Remove your web.xml
2. Remove your desk-servlet.xml
3. Add an application.properties
4. Create a runnable class

1 and 2 are quite self explaining.

Create an `application.properties` file in `src\main\resources` containing the settings for your datasource. For more properties see [this section in the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-configure-datasource) and the list of [properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/desk_db;instance=SQLEXPRESS
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
```

Create a runnable class to bootstrap your application.

```
package com.myapplication.desk;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public static MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Now either just run this class to bootstrap your application or use `gradlew -bootRun`. I prefer to just run this class.

Spring Boot will take care of setting up a `JdbcTemplate` and `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` based on what it detects on the classpath. It will also take care of exposing `/resources` so that those are available on the web. This happens due to the addition of [`@EnableAutoConfiguration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html#getting-started-first-application-auto-configuration).

I strongly suggest a read of the Spring Boot [Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/) and take a look at [the samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples)